# ORA-00972 Oracle EF Provider

Tags: oracle, entity-framework

I'm using EF with the `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client` provider and I keep getting the following error when querying the database.

> "ORA-00972: identifier is too long"

After some research online I found that this error was due to Oracle's 30 character alias limit which I am exceeding. This error was reported over two years ago and it seems that the error hasn't been fixed in the latest version of the provider.

Unfortunately the database is a 3rd party solution and I cannot modify the database in anyway.

**Is it possible to force EF to generate aliases less than 30 characters?**

My problem seems to arise when joining multiple tables with where conditions applied. I'm also only selecting/projecting the columns I need however EF is projecting all columns in the join producing the the unecessary alias.

I would expect this...

```
SELECT 
  tbl1.key
FROM Table1 tbl1
INNER JOIN Table2 tbl2 on tbl1.key = tbl2.key
WHERE blah blah blah
```

But instead I get this...

```
SELECT 
  tbl1.col1
FROM (SELECT tbl1.col1, tbl1.col2, tbl1.col3, tbl1.col4, tbl1.col5 from Table1 tbl1
  INNER JOIN Table2 tbl2 on tbl1.key = tbl2.key WHERE blah blah blah)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, i'm facing the same problem. On my Db exist 30 characters column's name long and EF generates alias with 31 characers.